# C++Builder app reciving constant WM_MOUSEMOVE messages when mouse cursor is just sitting over the active form?

Tags: winapi, c++builder

I added a `TApplicationEvents::OnMessage` handler to the primary form, and have it output debug information on mouse movements, key presses, etc.

When the mouse is hovered over the active form (even if I open another form, over top of that form), there is consistently `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages being sent, non-stop.  If I move the mouse outside of the active form, even if over the parent form, it stops.

Is there a setting in C++Builder for a form or the app to control this behavior?  What could be causing this?

Comment: WM_MOUSEMOVE can also be generated when a window receives the focus, even though the mouse didn't move.  So if you set a breakpoint on OnMessage() and it hits, to immediately continue running then you'll indeed see a mouse move message over and over again.  Tough cases requires using the remote debugging feature.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't set a break point - but it seems that linked article suggests that maybe when they update the event window they do it in a way that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that output to the `Event Window` of the C++Builder IDE causes spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages.

After reading [Why do I get a spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE message whenever Resource Manager is running?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160616-00/?p=93685) and that got me thinking maybe it was the C++Builder IDE Event Window itself that is causing the extra messages.

I closed down the IDE, fired up `DebugView` and launched the app from the command line.  Sure enough, no more problems.  I only get `WM_MOUSEMOVE` when moving the mouse.

I think this is a new issue with the IDE because I had tested this with the initial 11.3 version I had and it was working fine.  I actually just uncommented the debug output code that was already there.

Comment: "*I think this is a new issue with the IDE*" - then feel free to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero

Comment: Updated comment: I am experiencing this issue. I filed [RSP-42172](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-42172). Note that there are numerous duplicates created due to QP not behaving well. :(